# Loading local video into VideoView faster

Tags: android, video

I have a local video which is played on app launch using the VideoView layout.
Sometimes / on certain devices, it takes several seconds (5-10 seconds) until it starts playing, resulting in a black screen until the video actually starts.

This is how I load and play the video:

```
private void playVideo() {
    Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.app_video);
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);        
    videoView.start();
}
```

The video is 4.6MB and in .m4v format.

Is there any way to make it faster? different format? different library to play videos? load it ahead of time?

Any optimization suggestion will be welcome.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: @AnjalSaneen Unfortunately not..

Comment: I have tried a lot, I couldn't find the solution, later I added exo player. its great

Comment: Works better for local videos as well?

Comment: Yes, working well with local video.